# Value from previous week in new column

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe:

```
                    Open    High    Low     Last    Vol_POC Week
Timestamp                       
2016-09-27 02:00:00 165.50  165.58  165.46  165.47  165.98  39
2016-09-27 03:00:00 165.47  165.65  165.46  165.63  165.98  39
2016-09-27 04:00:00 165.64  165.92  165.59  165.91  165.98  39
2016-09-27 05:00:00 165.91  166.13  165.91  165.97  165.98  39
2016-09-27 06:00:00 165.98  165.98  165.76  165.78  165.98  39
2016-09-27 07:00:00 165.79  166.04  165.79  166.02  165.98  39
```

The `Week` value was created using this code:

```
data['Week']=[r.week for r in data.index]
```

I now want a new column `Vol_POC_last_week` giving the value for `Vol_POC` of the previous week.  So for example, any row with `Week` value `40` I would have the `Vol_POC` value for `Week` `39` etc.

Can you please show how I would do this?

**edit:**

I took the answer from @I159 and modified it with [DateOffset](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#dateoffset-objects). 
`data['last_week'] = pd.Index(data.index).to_datetime() - pd.offsets.Week(1)` `data['Prior VPOC'] = data.loc[data.last_week, "Vol POC"].values`

Comment: May you show us your current solution. Perhaps we could improve your solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do it this way:

```
data["Vol_POC_last_week"] = pd.Series()                                               
data.loc[data.Week == 40, "Vol_POC_last_week"] = data.loc[data.Week == 39, "Vol_POC"].values
```

#### `pandas.DataFrame.loc`

> DataFrame.loc
>   Purely label-location based indexer for selection by label.

The `.loc` attribute is the primary access method gives access to a value not to a copy of it.

It has simple and obvious interface:

`.loc[row_indexer,column_indexer]`

#### *Multi line change*

```
for i in data.Week.unique()[:-1]:
    data.loc[data.Week == i, "Vol_POC_last_week"] = data.loc[data.Week == i-1, "Vol_POC"].values
```

Since we need to make changes according to a particular value of `Week` column and it is not unique the only way I see now is just the same but iterative.

Comment: Thanks.  How do I do this for each week so not just week 39?

Comment: @adele, do you store all the week values in the same data frame or you have separated data frames for each week?

Comment: I expanded on your idea and did this: 'data['last_week'] = pd.Index(data.index).to_datetime() - pd.offsets.Week(1)' then 'data['Prior VPOC'] = data.loc[data.last_week, "Vol POC"].values'

Comment: I tried the multiline but get 'ValueError: Must have equal len keys and value when setting with an iterable'  Never mind I have my required output as per my last post which covers the answer.  I will mark as accepted.